# Jquery, select all element with a class

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

someone could tell me why this code works correctly on chorme but not on the other browsers?

```
  $("#"+grid+" tr:nth-of-type(2) td.table_view_tablet").each(function() {
       id = $(this).attr('aria-describedby');
       id = id.split("_");
       jQuery("#"+grid).jqGrid('hideCol', [""+id[2]+""]);
  });
```

I'want to select all ceil with class "table_view_tablet" in the second line of table "grid"

My HTML code is similar to this:

```
    <table id="mailing_grid" aria-labelledby="gbox_mailing_grid" aria-multiselectable="false" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="ui-jqgrid-btable" role="grid" style="width: 1039px;" tabindex="0">
      <tr class="jqgfirstrow" role="row" style="height: auto">
            <td role="gridcell" style="height: 0px; width: 47px;"></td>
            <td role="gridcell" style="height: 0px; width: 47px;"></td>
            <td role="gridcell" style="height: 0px; width: 78px;"></td>
            <td role="gridcell" style="height: 0px; width: 116px;"></td>
            <td role="gridcell" style="height: 0px; width: 116px;"></td>
            <td role="gridcell" style="height: 0px; width: 78px;"></td>
            <td role="gridcell" style="height: 0px; width: 116px;"></td>
            <td role="gridcell" style="height: 0px; width: 31px;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-state-highlight" role="row" tabindex="0">
            <td aria-describedby="mailing_grid_CSCDML" class="table_view_mobile" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">1</td>
            <td aria-describedby="mailing_grid_CSCDCS" class="table_view_mobile" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">2</td>
            <td aria-describedby="mailing_grid_CSNMCS" class="table_view_mobile" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">3</td>
            <td aria-describedby="mailing_grid_CSDSCS" class="table_view_mobile" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">4</td>
            <td aria-describedby="mailing_grid_CSADR" class="table_view_desktop" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">5</td>
            <td aria-describedby="mailing_grid_CSCDZP" class="table_view_desktop" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">6</td>
            <td aria-describedby="mailing_grid_CSCITY" class="table_view_mobile" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">7</td>
            <td aria-describedby="mailing_grid_CSCDCY" class="table_view_mobile" role="gridcell" style="text-align: left;">8</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML as well, that would help answer your question.

Comment: Try it using tr:eq(2), because this is the correcty jQuery slector for nth element, and > as spacing.

Comment: http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something that is a bit more jQuery-driven instead of CSS-driven, so that you do not need to rely on the browser support of the CSS properties / selectors:

```
var $grid = $('#' + grid);

$grid
    .find('tr')
    .eq(2)
    .find('td.table_view_tablet')
    .each(function(){
        var $self = $(this);

        $grid.jqGrid('hideCol',[
            $self.attr('aria-describedby').split('_')[2]
        ]);
    });
```

Without your HTML or a jsFiddle I can't confirm this works as expected, but it is the same objective of the code you were implementing prior done in a less CSS-driven manner. This also has the benefit of leveraging caching, so it may potentially be faster. That said, a potential improvement, assuming `jqGrid` works as I assume it does:

```
var $grid = $('#' + grid),
    hideColArr = [];

$grid
    .find('tr')
    .eq(2)
    .find('td.table_view_tablet')
    .each(function(){
        hideColArr[hideColArr.length] = $(this).attr('aria-describedby').split('_')[2];
    });

$grid.jqGrid('hideCol',hideColArr);
```

This way you don't call `jqGrid` more than the one time you need. Again, making assumptions here, but considering you're passing an array this should work as you want without performing unnecessary calls.